# How do I migrate Process Automation Settings -> Enable record locking and unlocking using ANT Migration Tool or ChangeSet or Metadata API

Tags: metadata-api, change-set, migration-tool, migration, process-automation-settings

How do I migrate setting `Process Automation Settings -> Enable record locking and unlocking` using **ANT Migration Tool** or **ChangeSet** or **Metadata API**?

We need to migrate checkbox checked in settings between several organizations.

Answer (score 2):

Package.xml

```
<types>
    <members>OrgPreference</members>
    <name>Settings</name>
</types>
```

Look for lines

```
<preferences>
    <settingName>ApexApprovalLockUnlock</settingName>
    <settingValue>true</settingValue>
</preferences>
```

Answer (score 0):

As of API v48.0, `ApexApprovalLockUnlock` [has been moved](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_orgpreferencesettings.htm) to `ApexSettings`.

**Note:** the setting currently doesn't display as an option in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_apexsettings.htm), but if you retrieve the `ApexSettings` from an org, the setting will show in `Apex.settings-meta.xml` as `enableApexApprovalLockUnlock`.